Fabricating a 6x6 post
In post frame construction, 6x6 posts (nominal 5.5"x5.5") are commonly used.
Is it possible to fabricate a 6x6 post using four 2 3/4" x 2 3/4" posts using structural screws only (no adhesive and no bolts) such that:

The fabricated post has similar or better compression properties as a non-fabricated post

The fabricated post has similar or better bending strength as a non-fabricated post



It depends. In wood construction, the building codes allow fabricating larger posts out of smaller boards that are nailed together, typically when the resulting post is loaded in compression. But for beams loaded in bending (floor joists, etc.) this practice is often prohibited because a nailed joint cannot be as strong in shear as a beam made from a solid piece of lumber.

If you had 3 side by side 2x12s nailed together, couldn't you take the bending capacity as being that of a single 2x12 times 3?  As opposed to whatever the equivalent single piece of equal final dimensions?  I know when I first started out, my boss custom designed a plywood girder to clear span an indoor pool.  Her calculations showed she only needed to make it 3 sheets thick, so she told the contractor to build it with 5 sheet thicknesses, gave a stagger pattern for both the sheet layout and nailing pattern and had them smear glue between each layer.  Cheaper than a custom glulam beam!
